# Stack Exchange API doesn't work for meta sites

Tags: support, per-site-meta, api

The Stack Exchange API doesn't seem to be working for certain sites like meta.stackoverflow.com.

For example, the below API to get the answers to a question by ID doesn't work for the [following question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396516/6908282).

- API ref: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=394498&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true
- Question link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/396516/6908282

Comment: In case you find non-meta site where it happens, feel free to roll back my edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please note that https://meta.stackoverflow.com is a different site than https://stackoverflow.com. Click the [edit] link next to the site name:

[image]

and type Meta Stack Overflow. When you run the query again, you'll get results:

[image]

([direct link](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=394498&filter=default&site=meta.stackoverflow&run=true))

Comment: check out [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395847/381523) for the api site name for each site