# Stack Exchange site names for API URL query parameter

Tags: discussion, support, api

When calling a Stack Exchange API we need to specify which site  we are trying to fetch the data from in a API URL query parameter (`site=webapps.meta`) like below:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions#ids=4882&filter=default&site=webapps.meta
```

This is not consistent across sites. For example:

| Site | Site URL | query parameter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Stack Overlow | https://stackoverflow.com/ | `site=stackoverflow` |
| Meta Stack Exchange | https://meta.stackexchange.com/ | `site=meta` |
| Web Application Meta | https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/ | `site=webapps.meta` |
| MathOverflow | https://mathoverflow.net/ | `site=mathoverflow.net` |

---

My questions is, is this documented anywhere on what should be the site query parameter for the respective site?

Comment: From the [docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) in paragraph "Per-Site Methods" *Each of these methods operates on a single site at a time, identified by the site parameter. This parameter can be the full domain name (ie. "stackoverflow.com"), or a short form identified by api_site_parameter on the site object.*  So `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=webapps.meta.stackexchange.com` works as well

Comment: Oh, this is good input @rene. Thank you for sharing this. This will be the straight-forward way to construct a query. Would you mind adding this as an answer?

Answer (score 7):

You can query this using the API:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/sites

Look for the `api_site_parameter` property in the output.

Find the documentation at [Usage of /sites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) and the types it returns at [Type Site](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site).

Answer (score 5):

What @rene says in the comments is absolutely the best advice:

> From the [docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) in paragraph "Per-Site Methods" *Each of these methods operates on a single site at a time, identified by the site parameter. This parameter can be the full domain name (ie. "stackoverflow.com"), or a short form identified by api_site_parameter on the site object.*  So `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=webapps.meta.stackexchange.com` works as well

I never heeded that advice, so I ended up with lots of exceptional cases in my scripts. Well, I probably needed such type of code anyway; try to guess the pattern for the iOS favicons for *all* sites from this URL: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png. And there's another system in the landscape with sometimes surprising identifiers; I posted about that here: [How can I get URLs and site names for a cross-site SEDE query?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359794/295232)

While @rene's solution is **definitely** the best way to go forward, if you want to insist on the original parameters:

1. For the main Stack Overflow site, use `stackoverflow`
2. If the host ends with `.stackexchange.com`, use its prefix
3. If the host ends with `.stackoverflow.com`, use its prefix and add `.stackoverflow`
4. Strip the `.com` suffix from the host (if it's present), and use the result.

Or use the one-liner from [@Makyen's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/395857/295232), since it's much easier. I tried to reverse engineer an algorithm based on a piece of code which (partially) does the opposite - no wonder it's not optimised.

Comment: FYI: the steps you've listed are equivalent to `domain.replace('.stackexchange.com', '').replace('.com', '')` in all cases for the canonical domain names. If you simplify your steps, then I can just delete my answer. :;

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right, that's what you get when you try to reverse engineer an algorithm based on a piece of code which (partially) does the opposite :D

Answer (score 2):

As [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene) said in [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395847/stack-exchange-site-names-for-api-url-query-parameter#comment1324120_395847), the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs#tabs), under the "Per-Site Methods" heading, says:

> Each of these methods operates on a single site at a time, identified by the `site` parameter. This parameter can be the full domain name (ie. "stackoverflow.com"), or a short form identified by `api_site_parameter` on the [site object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site).

##### Getting the `api_site_parameter` from the `/sites` SE API endpoint

You can use the api.stackexchange.com site to compose test requests. For the `/sites` endpoint, a request which gets the `site_url`, `api_site_parameter`, and `name` for all sites can be seen [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=1000&filter=!3ynpfT-W2tkN1Ilq0&run=true).

##### Computing the `api_site_parameter` from the site's canonical domain name

In addition, it's possible to compute the `api_site_parameter` value from the site's domain with simple string replacement. The following is valid code to get the `api_site_parameter` from the site's canonical domain name in at least Python and JavaScript. For other languages, adjust to the appropriate syntax:

```
domain.replace('.stackexchange.com', '').replace('.com', '')
```

will give you the `api_site_parameter` for all existing sites when using the canonical domain for the site, not an alias.

You can see site aliases with [this SE API request](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=1000&filter=!b1aoo2LP-iAzfC&run=true). If you want to be fully complete, then you'll need to do a lookup based on the domain name, including all the aliases. However, most of the code I've seen ignores the aliases.

Comment: *sigh* ... ninja'd :; This answer was made largely redundant by Glorfindel's answer, which I didn't notice was posted while I was composing this one. I'm leaving it up, as the string replacement steps are useful.

Comment: Yeah, those Stack Apps mods ruin all your fun ...

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

Erik has pointed out in the comments that the list is paginated so the below list is not the complete list. You can use the `pagesize=5000` as suggested to get all the data. I have done the same thing in the [following excel](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1za8zIQ3d0N5_HC6Lbiflo6Z31j0pU3qE/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=110535706239739151339&rtpof=true&sd=true) using the Excel Power Query to fetch data and create a table (for future reference).

> Note: Download the excel and refresh the Power Query to fetch the data again. But do note that refreshing the Power Query consumes your API quota (max 300)

---

Thanks to @Erik's answer, below is the list of site names to be used in API extracted from the API - https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/sites

| Site Name | Site URL | api_site_parameter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Stack Overflow | https://stackoverflow.com | stackoverflow |
| Server Fault | https://serverfault.com | serverfault |
| Super User | https://superuser.com | superuser |
| Meta Stack Exchange | https://meta.stackexchange.com | meta |
| Web Applications | https://webapps.stackexchange.com | webapps |
| Web Applications Meta | https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com | webapps.meta |
| Arqade | https://gaming.stackexchange.com | gaming |
| Arqade Meta | https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com | gaming.meta |
| Webmasters | https://webmasters.stackexchange.com | webmasters |
| Webmasters Meta | https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com | webmasters.meta |
| Seasoned Advice | https://cooking.stackexchange.com | cooking |
| Seasoned Advice Meta | https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com | cooking.meta |
| Game Development | https://gamedev.stackexchange.com | gamedev |
| Game Development Meta | https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com | gamedev.meta |
| Photography | https://photo.stackexchange.com | photo |
| Photography Meta | https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com | photo.meta |
| Cross Validated | https://stats.stackexchange.com | stats |
| Cross Validated Meta | https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com | stats.meta |
| Mathematics | https://math.stackexchange.com | math |
| Mathematics Meta | https://math.meta.stackexchange.com | math.meta |
| Home Improvement | https://diy.stackexchange.com | diy |
| Home Improvement Meta | https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com | diy.meta |
| Meta Super User | https://meta.superuser.com | meta.superuser |
| Meta Server Fault | https://meta.serverfault.com | meta.serverfault |
| Geographic Information Systems | https://gis.stackexchange.com | gis |
| Geographic Information Systems Meta | https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com | gis.meta |
| TeX - LaTeX | https://tex.stackexchange.com | tex |
| TeX - LaTeX Meta | https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com | tex.meta |
| Ask Ubuntu | https://askubuntu.com | askubuntu |
| Ask Ubuntu Meta | https://meta.askubuntu.com | meta.askubuntu |

Comment: Note that there are many more sites than that, that request is paginated. For the unpaginated variant, pass a large pagesize: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/sites?pagesize=50000. But listing them all in an answer doesn't really seem sensible to me.

Comment: Oh, is there any other API to fetch the site details of a specific site then?

Comment: You know there are docs for that endpoint, right? https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites which  return a list of sites: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site.

Comment: @Gangula Of course, the /info endpoint. It requires a filter to get the api_site_parameter, e.g. https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/info?site=superuser.com&filter=!nNPvSNZIS6

Comment: But to use the `/info` API, we need to know the `api_site_parameter` right?

Comment: Or the URL, since you can just use that, as rene indicated in his comment on your question. No clue how you'd want to fetch info on a specific site without knowing the URL.